# How to change Bootstrap 4 tooltip opacity?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

What do I need to target to change the opacity for Bootstrap 4? I found that I need to target this to affect its background, but when I add opacity:1 to tooltip-inner or tooltip, it does nothing:

```
.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #014379;
}

.tooltip .arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #014379;
}
```

What do I need to do to change it?
Thanks!

Comment: have you try like this .tooltip.show {opacity: 0.5;}

Comment: Thanks Muhammad, this worked perfectly! If you want, add an answer so I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the opacity of tooltip like this

```
.tooltip.show {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: You may need to add an `!important` to that or use a more specific selector (check what selectors Bootstrap is using?), since it doesn't seem to work by itself.

Comment: Works in Bootstrap 5 too, thx!

Answer (score 2):

If you've tried tried this code

```
.tooltip.show /* The CSS classes that the tooltip has */ {
    opacity: 0.5; /* or whatever */
}
```

Then try to add `!important`, so that you can be sure that your style will be applied

```
opacity: 0.5 !important;
```

If it still doesn't work, feel free to tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Opacity has a value between 0 and 1. 1 being nothing changed at all and 0 being invicible.

```css
.tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #014379;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.tooltip .arrow:before {
  border-top-color: #014379;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
        Tooltip on bottom
    </button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color opacity, you could use rgba()
though it will not work with HEX colors unless you use SCSS
that means if you want this solution you will need to find a color that looks like `#014379` but with rgb()

RGBA Example:

```
/*Instead of 
background-color: #014379;
*/
background-color:rgba(XXX,XXX,XXX,0.5)
```

SCSS Example:

SCSS Variable:

```
$color-tertiary: #607D8B;
```

Change Opacity:

```
background-color: rgba($color-tertiary, 0.5);
```